# Block the "cms" tag

Tags: support, retagging

There are 124 questions on SO that are tagged with both [wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) and [cms](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cms).
[cms](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cms) should probably be blocked, to avoid that questions migrated from SO keep that tag once migrated on *WordPress Answers*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CMS in context of WordPress has historically formed bit of special meaning - using WordPress further from usual (blogging/posts) and closer to generic CMS (pages/CPT/whatever).

I don't see the tag as problematic at moment. If used at WPSE it is usually adequate, if migrated in - well, there are a lot of possible issues with migrated posts. How it's done on other sites of network shouldn't overly influence our set of tags.